# Json ajax post returning 403 error

Tags: json, ajax, post, http-status-code-403

I'm passing to my php application a json via ajax post.

```
function ajax(url, json){

    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.timeout = 30000;
    xmlhttp.send(json);

}
```

In my development environment (A.K.A. XAMPP on my own computer) everything works fine, but when I try to run it in my web server I get a 403 error.

I noticed that when I pass any other value, like a simple string or number, I don't get this error. It just happens when I try to post some json, like:

```
[[],[["6V^1",[],6]],1,"","",""]
```

Any clues of whats is going on and how I can solve this problem?